# Trigger.isUpdate Condition not covering in test class

Tags: trigger, unit-test

here is test class

```
@isTest
    public class SubjectTriggerHandler_Test{
        public static testMethod void unitTest() {
          CTMS__Program__c Program = new CTMS__Program__c();
        Program.Name = 'test';
        Program.CTMS__Description__c = 'abcd';
        insert Program ;  
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',Program.id);

        CTMS__Address__c addressObj = new CTMS__Address__c();
        addressObj.CTMS__City__c = 'Nasik';
        addressObj.CTMS__Postal_Code__c = '422003';
        addressObj.CTMS__Street_Address__c = 's';
        addressObj.CTMS__State__c = 'PA';
        insert addressObj;

        //Inserting Region
        CTMS__Region__c regionObj = new CTMS__Region__c();
        regionObj.CTMS__Region__c = 'USA';
        regionObj.CTMS__Protocol_Number__c = '111';
        insert regionObj;

        //Inserting Contact
        Contact conObj = new Contact();
        conObj.lastName = 'Barr,MD';
        conObj.Department = 'Finance';
        insert conObj;

        CTMS__Clinical_Site__c siteObj = new CTMS__Clinical_Site__c();
        siteObj.CTMS__Site_Name__c = 'test site2';
        siteObj.CTMS__Currency_Code__c = 'USD';
        siteObj.CTMS__Site_Address__c = addressObj.id;
        siteObj.CTMS__Region__c = regionObj.id;
        siteObj.CTMS__Primary_Investigator__c = conObj.id;
        siteObj.CTMS__Address__c = addressObj.id;
        siteObj.CTMS__Program__c= Program.id;
        siteObj.CTMS__Site__c = '2027';
        insert siteObj;

         CTMS__Clinical_Site__c siteObj2 = new CTMS__Clinical_Site__c();
        siteObj2.CTMS__Site_Name__c = 'test site2';
        siteObj2.CTMS__Currency_Code__c = 'USD';
        siteObj2.CTMS__Site_Address__c = addressObj.id;
        siteObj2.CTMS__Region__c = regionObj.id;
        siteObj2.CTMS__Primary_Investigator__c = conObj.id;
        siteObj2.CTMS__Address__c = addressObj.id;
        siteObj2.CTMS__Program__c= Program.id;
        siteObj2.CTMS__Site__c = '2027';
        insert siteObj2;


        CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c subjVisit = new CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c();
        subjVisit.CTMS__Visit_Name__c = 'test';
        subjVisit.CTMS__Site__c = siteObj.id;
        insert subjVisit;

        CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c subjVisit2 = new CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c();
        subjVisit2.CTMS__Visit_Name__c = 'test';
        subjVisit2.CTMS__Site__c = siteObj.id;

        insert subjVisit2;

        subjVisit.CTMS__Site__c =  siteObj2.id;
        update subjVisit;

        CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c subjVisit3 = new CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c();
        subjVisit3.CTMS__Visit_Name__c = 'test';
        subjVisit3.CTMS__Site__c = siteObj.id;



        delete subjVisit;

        undelete subjVisit;
        System.assertNotEquals(subjVisit2,null);


        }
    }
```

here is my Trigger

```
trigger SubjectVisitCount on CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c (After insert, After update, After delete, After undelete) {
   Set<Id> Ids = new Set<Id>();
    if(!Trigger.isDelete){
        for ( CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c  sv : Trigger.new) {        
            if(Trigger.isInsert && sv.CTMS__Site__c != null){
                Ids.add(sv.CTMS__Site__c);
            }

            if(Trigger.isUpdate){
                **if(sv.CTMS__Site__c==null && Trigger.oldMap.get(sv.Id).CTMS__Site__c != null){**
                    Ids.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(sv.Id).CTMS__Site__c);
                }
            **if(sv.CTMS__Site__c!=null && Trigger.oldMap.get(sv.Id).CTMS__Site__c != null && sv.CTMS__Site__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(sv.Id).CTMS__Site__c){**
                Ids.add(sv.CTMS__Site__c);
                Ids.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(sv.Id).CTMS__Site__c);
            }
            if(sv.CTMS__Site__c!=null && Trigger.oldMap.get(sv.Id).CTMS__Site__c == null){
                Ids.add(sv.CTMS__Site__c);
            }
        }

        if(Trigger.isUndelete && sv.CTMS__Site__c != null){
            Ids.add(sv.CTMS__Site__c);
        }
    }
    }else{
        for (CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c  sv : Trigger.old){
            if(Trigger.isDelete && sv.CTMS__Site__c != null){
                Ids.add(sv.CTMS__Site__c);
            }
        }   
    }

    if(Ids.size()>0){
        SubjectTriggerHandler.perform(Ids);
   }
}
```

here is Handler Class

```
public class SubjectTriggerHandler {
    public static void perform(Set<Id> Ids){
      List<CTMS__Clinical_Site__c> CSToUpdate = new List<CTMS__Clinical_Site__c>();
      List<AggregateResult> cont=[Select Count(Id) ContactCount, CTMS__Site__c from CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c where CTMS__Site__c IN: Ids GROUP BY CTMS__Site__c];

        for (AggregateResult ar: cont){
            CTMS__Clinical_Site__c acc = new CTMS__Clinical_Site__c(Id=(Id)ar.get('CTMS__Site__c'), Subject_Visit_Count__c=(Integer)ar.get('ContactCount'));
            CSToUpdate.add(acc);
        }

           update CSToUpdate;  
    }
 }
```

Comment: Providing the code is very helpful, so thanks for doing that from the start! Your question could use some more elaboration though (what exactly isn't being covered?). I assume that the `if()` blocks marked with `**` in the provided code are the ones that you're not getting coverage for. I'll start typing up an answer based on that assumption, but it would be nice if you could confirm this.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is primarily an issue of test setup. The structure of your test could be improved (mostly by breaking your current single test method into multiple test methods, and making more assertions), but I'll focus on the test setup here.

After studying the provided code, it looks like the focus is on the following block

```
for ( CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c  sv : Trigger.new) {        
    if(Trigger.isInsert && sv.CTMS__Site__c != null){
        Ids.add(sv.CTMS__Site__c);
    }

    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        // This if block should not be covered by the current test
        if(sv.CTMS__Site__c==null && Trigger.oldMap.get(sv.Id).CTMS__Site__c != null){
            Ids.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(sv.Id).CTMS__Site__c);
        }
        // This if block should be covered by the current test
        if(sv.CTMS__Site__c!=null && Trigger.oldMap.get(sv.Id).CTMS__Site__c != null && sv.CTMS__Site__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(sv.Id).CTMS__Site__c){
            Ids.add(sv.CTMS__Site__c);
            Ids.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(sv.Id).CTMS__Site__c);
        }
        // This if block should not be covered by the current test
        if(sv.CTMS__Site__c!=null && Trigger.oldMap.get(sv.Id).CTMS__Site__c == null){
            Ids.add(sv.CTMS__Site__c);
        }
    }

    if(Trigger.isUndelete && sv.CTMS__Site__c != null){
        Ids.add(sv.CTMS__Site__c);
    }
}
```

The two if blocks not getting coverage means that your test setup isn't providing the right conditions for these blocks to be executed (and therefore covered).

The blocks not being covered are inside a `Trigger.isUpdate()` block. Let's look at your current setup for testing the update behavior.

```
CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c subjVisit2 = new CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c();
subjVisit2.CTMS__Visit_Name__c = 'test';
subjVisit2.CTMS__Site__c = siteObj.id;

insert subjVisit2;

subjVisit.CTMS__Site__c =  siteObj2.id;
update subjVisit;
```

So, `CTMS__Site__c` is populated, and is being changed to a different, non-null value in an update.

You have 3 if blocks which check `CTMS__Site__c` for the following:

1. Was this field previously populated, and is being changed to null?
2. Was this field previously populated, and is being changed to another, non-null value?
3. Was this field previously null, and is now being populated?

The test setup you've done only covers case #2 (previously populated, updated to another non-null value). These 3 cases are mutually exclusive (meaning that it's only possible to satisfy one of the conditions at a time). To get coverage for the other two cases, you'll need to perform additional setup.

At the bare minimum, you could expand your test code to the following:

```
CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c subjVisit2 = new CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c();
subjVisit2.CTMS__Visit_Name__c = 'test';
subjVisit2.CTMS__Site__c = siteObj.id;

insert subjVisit2;

// Existing code, Covers case #2 (non-null => non-null)
subjVisit.CTMS__Site__c =  siteObj2.id;
update subjVisit;

// New code, Covers case #1 (non-null => null)
subjVisit.CTMS__Site__c =  null;
update subjVisit;

// New code, Covers case #3 (null => non-null)
subjVisit.CTMS__Site__c =  siteObj2.id;
update subjVisit;
```

All that said, the above gets you coverage, but covered != tested. For testing, you need assertions. In this case, it's a bit hard to test the trigger. The trigger isn't directly making any changes to any records, but rather calls out to a helper class to do the work.

There are two things you could possibly want to test here:

1. Test to ensure that your trigger calls (or doesn't call) your helper class in various situations
2. Test to ensure that the end result of the trigger causes records to be updated (you'd be looking at changes to `CTMS__Clinical_Site__c` records here)

number 2 is easier to make assertions against, but is more appropriate for the unit testing of `SubjectTriggerHandler` rather than the unit test for the trigger that uses this class.

number 1 is more appropriate for the trigger's unit test, but I don't think it's possible to follow best practices for this type of unit test when you're working directly with a trigger (I'd want to use dependency injection and a mock/stub for `SubjectTriggerHandler` to do this). We can introduce a static variable in `SubjectTriggerHandler` to accomplish this.

The big arguments for having many, smaller test methods instead of one huge test method are:

- Smaller test methods are (hopefully) easier and faster to write
- Smaller test methods, with very specific test inputs, make it easier to find and fix bugs
- Smaller test methods make it harder to run up against the governor limits

My final recommendation for your code ends up looking something like this:

Helper class:

```
public class SubjectTriggerHandler {
    // New static variable which can be used to assert against in tests
    public static Integer timesCalled = 0;

    public static void perform(Set<Id> Ids){
      // Increment the count every time this method is called
      SubjectTriggerHandler.timesCalled++;

      List<CTMS__Clinical_Site__c> CSToUpdate = new List<CTMS__Clinical_Site__c>();
      List<AggregateResult> cont=[Select Count(Id) ContactCount, CTMS__Site__c from CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c where CTMS__Site__c IN: Ids GROUP BY CTMS__Site__c];

        for (AggregateResult ar: cont){
            CTMS__Clinical_Site__c acc = new CTMS__Clinical_Site__c(Id=(Id)ar.get('CTMS__Site__c'), Subject_Visit_Count__c=(Integer)ar.get('ContactCount'));
            CSToUpdate.add(acc);
        }

           update CSToUpdate;  
    }
 }
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
    public class SubjectTriggerHandler_Test{
        static CTMS__Clinical_Site__c testSite1;
        static CTMS__Clinical_Site__c testSite2;
        static CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c testVisit;

        public static setup(){
            // Do the common setup once, in a single location, so it can be reused
            // Using an @testSetup annotated method instead would be preferred,
            // but I find this pattern simpler, and don't want to bother with the extra hoops required for using data generated in an @testSetup method.

            CTMS__Program__c Program = new CTMS__Program__c();
            Program.Name = 'test';
            Program.CTMS__Description__c = 'abcd';
            insert Program ;  
            ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',Program.id);

            CTMS__Address__c addressObj = new CTMS__Address__c();
            addressObj.CTMS__City__c = 'Nasik';
            addressObj.CTMS__Postal_Code__c = '422003';
            addressObj.CTMS__Street_Address__c = 's';
            addressObj.CTMS__State__c = 'PA';
            insert addressObj;

            //Inserting Region
            CTMS__Region__c regionObj = new CTMS__Region__c();
            regionObj.CTMS__Region__c = 'USA';
            regionObj.CTMS__Protocol_Number__c = '111';
            insert regionObj;

            //Inserting Contact
            Contact conObj = new Contact();
            conObj.lastName = 'Barr,MD';
            conObj.Department = 'Finance';
            insert conObj;

            CTMS__Clinical_Site__c siteObj = new CTMS__Clinical_Site__c();
            siteObj.CTMS__Site_Name__c = 'test site2';
            siteObj.CTMS__Currency_Code__c = 'USD';
            siteObj.CTMS__Site_Address__c = addressObj.id;
            siteObj.CTMS__Region__c = regionObj.id;
            siteObj.CTMS__Primary_Investigator__c = conObj.id;
            siteObj.CTMS__Address__c = addressObj.id;
            siteObj.CTMS__Program__c= Program.id;
            siteObj.CTMS__Site__c = '2027';
            insert siteObj;

            testSite1 = siteObj;

            CTMS__Clinical_Site__c siteObj2 = new CTMS__Clinical_Site__c();
            siteObj2.CTMS__Site_Name__c = 'test site2';
            siteObj2.CTMS__Currency_Code__c = 'USD';
            siteObj2.CTMS__Site_Address__c = addressObj.id;
            siteObj2.CTMS__Region__c = regionObj.id;
            siteObj2.CTMS__Primary_Investigator__c = conObj.id;
            siteObj2.CTMS__Address__c = addressObj.id;
            siteObj2.CTMS__Program__c= Program.id;
            siteObj2.CTMS__Site__c = '2027';
            insert siteObj2;

            testSite2 = siteObj2;

            CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c subjVisit = new CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c();
            subjVisit.CTMS__Visit_Name__c = 'test';
            subjVisit.CTMS__Site__c = siteObj.id;
            insert subjVisit;

            testVisit = subjVisit;
        }

        public static testMethod void testInsertion(){
            setup();

            Integer previousCalls = SubjectTriggerHandler.timesCalled;
            CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c subjVisit = new CTMS__Subjects_Visit__c();
            subjVisit.CTMS__Visit_Name__c = 'test';
            subjVisit.CTMS__Site__c = testSite1.id;

            test.startTest();
            insert subjVisit;
            test.stopTest();

            system.assertEquals(previousCalls + 1, SubjectTriggerHandler.timesCalled, 'SubjectTriggerHandler was not called on insertion of visit');
       }

       public static testMethod void testUpdate1(){
           setup();
           Integer previousCalls = SubjectTriggerHandler.timesCalled;
           testVisit.CTMS__Site__c = null;

           test.startTest();
           update testVisit;
           test.stopTest();

           system.assertEquals(previousCalls + 1, SubjectTriggerHandler.timesCalled, 'SubjectTriggerHandler was not called on update of visit');
       }

       public static testMethod void testUpdate2(){
           setup();
           Integer previousCalls = SubjectTriggerHandler.timesCalled;
           testVisit.CTMS__Site__c = testSite2.Id;

           test.startTest();
           update testVisit;
           test.stopTest();

           system.assertEquals(previousCalls + 1, SubjectTriggerHandler.timesCalled, 'SubjectTriggerHandler was not called on update of visit');
       }

       public static testMethod void testUpdate3(){
           setup();

           // Need to do some additional setup for this test
           testVisit.CTMS__Site__c = null;
           update testVisit;

           // Now for the real test
           Integer previousCalls = SubjectTriggerHandler.timesCalled;
           testVisit.CTMS__Site__c = testSite2.Id;

           test.startTest();
           update testVisit;
           test.stopTest();

           system.assertEquals(previousCalls + 1, SubjectTriggerHandler.timesCalled, 'SubjectTriggerHandler was not called on update of visit');
       }

       /**
       * Remaining tests left for reader to implement.
       * They should follow the same general pattern as the tests above,
       * just testing different situations (like delete and undelete)
       */
    }
```